# Bash function comments before or inside the function

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Does the Bash language have a standard that dictates whether comments about the function should precede the function or be placed inside of it. I have seen scripts written both ways.

```
# Comment preceding function.
func1(){
echo "example"
}
```

-or-

```
func2() {
# Comment inside of function
echo "example"
}
```

Comment: There was a question here recently about encoding comments inside functions as `:` statements so that the functions could be self-documenting even under `declare`

Comment: Found it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/295022/117549

Comment: one common method is that comments ABOUT the function belong outside it, while comments DOCUMENTING (e.g. input and output) it belong inside.

Comment: The admin that closed this important topic could have put in some information that was useful before doing so IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most programming languages, the comments that describe what the function does go before the function. You should probably do the same for bash. You should also use indentation:

```
# function 1 comment
func1() {
    echo "example"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [examples](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/examples) from the official [bash repo](http://git://git.savannah.gnu.org/bash.git) comment **before** the function header and so does 
https://github.com/scop/bash-completion.

I don't think it matters much as long as it stays super easy to decipher for the person who'll be refactoring it 6 months from now (which might be you).

Here's another way to comment in shells:

```
:<<'DOC'
My 
multi 
line
comment
DOC
```

**Indentation** and **consistency** are generally nice to have too.